# 2 class style declaration in css doesn't work

Tags: css, class

I want to use CSS to style two different inputs, but in my CSS file use only one declaration for both classes. Here is what I tried

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="data_start" id="data_start" class="data_start" />
<input type="text" name="data_end" id="data_end" class="data_end" />
```

CSS:

```
.data_start .data_end { width:68px; margin-left:5px; }
```

If I use the code above, my inputs don't get styled, but if I do the following in my CSS file, it will work:

```
.data_start { width:68px; margin-left:5px; }
.data_end { width:68px; margin-left:5px; }
```

Can someone explain why the first CSS statement doesn't work?

Comment: try delimiting with a comma like `.data_start, .data_end {width:68px;margin-left:5px;}`

Comment: .data_start, .data_end {width:68px;margin-left:5px;}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.data_start .data_end` means an element `.data_end` *inside* a `.data_start` element.

`.data_start, .data_end` means it applies to `.data_start` and `.data_end` elements.

Comment: thanks, this made it more clear

Answer (score 2):

because you did something wrong:

```
.data_start .data_end {width:68px;margin-left:5px;}
```

is saying: search for `.data_end` inside `.data_start.`

```
.data_start, .data_end {width:68px;margin-left:5px;}
```

is saying search for `.data_start` or `.data_end`, see the comma ,

Comment: I think you mean "`.data_start` **or** `.data_end`", not "and". `.data_start.data_end` means elements that have `.data_start` **and** `.data_end`.

Comment: @veredesmarald: correct, edited.

Answer (score 1):

.data_start, .data_end {width:68px;margin-left:5px;}
Hi,

YOU NEED TO ADD ","

Answer (score 1):

You have to seperate there two `.data_start` AND `.data_end {width:68px;margin-left:5px;}` with comma

It should look like this: `.data_start, .data_end {width:68px;margin-left:5px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Use comma to separate those two

```
.data_start, .data_end {width:68px;margin-left:5px;}
```